# trouble withgroup by and value counts pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with case numbers and judges. Each case has multiple entries and I want to find how many cases a judge presided over.

It's a simple ask but one that's giving me different answers whichever way I try it.

I tried

```
df.groupby('judge')['case_number'].count()
```

as well as using value_counts() but none of them are returning what I expect.

sample df:

```
case_number                  case_status               actor    party_name  action  date_time   judge   file_date   status_date
0   1044SC000001    Disposed (Statistical Purposes) Plaintiff   Goodrow, Sandy  Fee paid    2010-01-08 00:00:00 Byrnes, Nathan A    20100101    20100303
1   1044SC000001    Disposed (Statistical Purposes) Plaintiff   Goodrow, Dennis Fee paid    2010-01-08 00:00:00 Byrnes, Nathan A    20100101    20100303
2   1044SC000001    Disposed (Statistical Purposes) Plaintiff   Basilone, Mario Fee paid    2010-01-08 00:00:00 Byrnes, Nathan A    20100101    20100303
3   1044SC000001    Disposed (Statistical Purposes) Plaintiff   Goodrow, Sandy  Fee paid    2010-01-08 00:00:00 Byrnes, Nathan A    20100101    20100303
4   1044SC000001    Disposed (Statistical Purposes) Plaintiff   Goodrow, Dennis Fee paid    2010-01-08 00:00:00 Byrnes, Nathan A    20100101    20100303


1043SC000027        Disposed (Statistical Purposes) Plaintiff   Performance Rehab Of Wne    Statement of small claim filed  2010-01-22 00:00:00 Poehler, Patricia T 20100101    20100308
51  1043SC000027    Disposed (Statistical Purposes) Plaintiff   Joseph, Roody   Statement of small claim filed  2010-01-22 00:00:00 Poehler, Patricia T 20100101    20100308
52  1043SC000027    Disposed (Statistical Purposes) Plaintiff   Performance Rehab Of Wne    Appearance filed    2010-01-22 00:00:00 Poehler, Patricia T 20100101    20100308
53  1043SC000027    Disposed (Statistical Purposes) Plaintiff   Joseph, Roody   Appearance filed    2010-01-22 00:00:00 Poehler, Patricia T 20100101    20100308
```

Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby('judge')['case_number'].nunique()`.